# Upgrading PSQL from 15 to 16, can upgrade client but not server

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-upgrade, postgresql-16

I have a server in which I wiped and booted with rhel9. I then used this resource to install psql 15 a couple months ago - https://www.tecmint.com/install-postgresql-and-pgadmin-rhel-9/
I am now trying to upgrade to psql16. I have installed pgsql16.

I was able to really quickly switch the client version using a link
sudo ln -sf /path/to/psql16 /usr/bin/psql

So now my psql version returns psql (16.1, server 15.3)

But I am unable to update the server version.

Here is the script I am trying to use within the postgres user:
/usr/pgsql-16/bin/pg_upgrade -b /usr/pgsql-15/bin/ -d 15/data/ -B /usr/pgsql-16/bin/ -D 16/data/

### I am getting this error:
Performing Consistency Checks

Checking cluster versions                                     ok

*failure*
Consult the last few lines of "16/data/pg_upgrade_output.d/20240112T172407.795/log/pg_upgrade_server.log" for
the probable cause of the failure.

connection to server on socket "/var/lib/pgsql/.s.PGSQL.50432" failed: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

could not connect to source postmaster started with the command:
"/usr/pgsql-15/bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "16/data/pg_upgrade_output.d/20240112T172407.795/log/pg_upgrade_server.log" -D "15/data" -o "-p 50432 -b  -c listen_addresses='' -c unix_socket_permissions=0700 -c unix_socket_directories='/var/lib/pgsql'" start
Failure, exiting

The log says:
pg_ctl: could not start server

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are the last few lines of `16/data/pg_upgrade_output.d/20240112T172407.795/log/pg_upgrade_server.log`?

Comment: update: I was getting this error because there was a syntax error in my pg_hba.conf file. Once I fixed that, pg_ugrade was able to work. Then once I started the postgresql-16 daemon, i was able to log onto psql through the postgres user account. However the version now displays: psql (13.13, server 16.1) upon login, meaning that the client is now 13.13 again when it was 16.1 earlier. edit: i attempted to fix this but doing the sudo ln -sf /path/to/psql16 command again, but i forgot to remove "/path/to/psql". Now when i try to use psql command, it says no such file or directory :0

Comment: fixed it, sometimes staying at the office after 5pm does more harm than good

Comment: Gotta get those Friday night deploys in. 